# What is the scripting language available in Soundbooth CS4?

Tags: plugins

Had to edit this to make it more clear.

In ExtendScript Toolkit I see a soundbooth object. It has only a handful of functions, one of which is called sendScriptToSoundbooth() which implies you can script Soundbooth().

What is the scripting language in soundbooth and how do you get started with scripting ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To [quote RJ Jacquez](http://blogs.adobe.com/rjacquez/2009/11/using_scripting_in_robohelp_8.html), a senior product evangelist at Adobe:

> One of the most powerful new features
>   in RoboHelp 8, which rarely gets
>   mentioned, is the new Scripting
>   engine, which Incidentally is **the same
>   scripting language also used in
>   Photoshop, Illustrator, Bridge,
>   Soundbooth and other CS4 products.**
>
> Put simply, the RoboHelp Scripting
>   Language is a Javascript-based
>   scripting language that exposes APIs
>   to invoke most of the basic
>   functionality of RoboHelp in an effort
>   to automate complex or repetitive
>   tasks.
>
> **For developing new scripts, all of our
>   Adobe applications with scripting
>   support use Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit
>   CS4**, which naturally ships with Adobe
>   RoboHelp 8.
>
> For more information about
>   ExtendScript Toolkit CS4, please [click
>   HERE](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/scripting/).

It appears SoundBooth does indeed use ExtendScript. The link in the quote points to the Adobe scripting center, where you can download the ExtendScript Toolkit and some PDFs to get you started on scripting.

Comment: Thank's for the effort John, but I've figured out the Soundbooth functions mentioned above(including sendScriptToSoundbooth()) by using ExtendScript Toolkit.I've tried to call basic functions like alert or print through the sendScript... function, but no result. All I got in the Javascript console is "Execution finished.". sendScriptToSoundbooth() suggests you send messages to soundbooth from extendscript toolkit, but in a different language. which one would that be ? any samples or documentation for scripting soundbooth ?

Comment: Can you add a link to a sample script/Hello World for Adobe Soundbooth please ? The guides available on the Devnet Scripting page covers most Adobe products, **except Soundbooth** :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes Adobe Soundbooth supports 3rd party plugins like [VST](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/403044).

More information on [VST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Studio_Technology), in case you are not familiar with it.

Comment: I didn't mean VST plugins, but thanks for the answer anyway. I'm more interested in scripting. Say I want to use Soundbooth for some features and export some data to Flash. I see I can connect to the app using ExtendScript Toolkit, but the only thing that works is app.quit(). There is no ObjectModel for Soundbooth, and among other listed functions which do not work, there is one called sendScriptToSoundbooth() which I imagine means you can actually script Soundbooth to do something for your, but not using ExtendScript Toolkit. I think I need to rephrase: How do you script Soundbooth ?